# Where are all the dead bodies in Last Man on Earth?

Tags: last-man-on-earth

In [Last Man on Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Man_on_Earth_(TV_series)),

> The year is 2020, Phil Miller (Will Forte) is seemingly the only human left on Earth after a deadly virus swept the planet one year earlier.

Was there any explanation of where all the dead bodies are?

Comment: Delicious, delicious soup.

Comment: Group migrated over to TWD series.

Comment: I watched most of the first season, and a) there was never any in-universe explanation presented, and b) I don't feel the show was looking for that sort of comprehensive continuity, more like "Here's a neat idea... go from there!"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Being a very unrealistic comedy on prime-time network TV, I doubt this will ever be truly answered in-universe. I'm not sure anyone has honestly given it much thought.

We've got a few quotes from people involved, but nothing concrete.  [Kirsten Schaal, who plays Carol theorizes](http://www.cinemablend.com/television/What-Happened-All-Dead-Bodies-Last-Man-Earth-71908.html):

> I think the biggest reason is the network didn’t want you to see them. I think they thought it would be a downer for a comedy… **I think all the bodies when the virus infects them, they disintegrate, as well as your clothing.**

The producers, Phil Lord and Chris Miller [also gave their take](http://www.vulture.com/2015/03/phil-lord-and-chris-miller-on-last-man-on-earth.html) and acknowledge that dead bodies just aren't funny, as well as the fact that they don't think Will Forte (creator, and Phil/Tandy Miller on the show) even has an answer for this himself.

> So, this is a television comedy about the apocalypse. I wanna focus on the apocalypse part of that. There are no bodies! Where did all the bodies go, what happened?
>
> Miller: **They’re just out of frame.** You can smell them if you’re on set, but we didn’t include them in the shots.
>
> Lord: I don’t know if Will has a rationale for what exactly happened. **In my mind, a bunch of animals gobbled up all the bodies, then they succumbed to the virus and then they died.**
>
> Miller: There have been a number of off-hand mentions of, “Hey, help me clear this body out of there,” or they drive by hospitals saying, “You do not want to go into there.” In general, we found that the more talk or visuals of dead bodies, the less hilarious it is.
>
> Lord: You wind up provoking two questions for every one that you answer, and we didn’t want the show to be about what happened, what was the virus like. We didn’t care about any of that stuff. We were interested in, how does a man deal with this new reality?